TYPO3 DCE remove “Select & Upload Files” button
I’m using TYPO3 v12 and DCE (Dynamic Content Elements) extension.
I have managed to remove the “Select & Upload Files” button from the standard content elements (Image, Image & Text, Media) with the following lines in TSConfig:
TCEFORM.tt_content.image.config.appearance.fileUploadAllowed = 0 TCEFORM.tt_content.assets.config.appearance.fileUploadAllowed = 0 
Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to remove the upload button within new elements created with DCE (Dynamic Content Elements) extension. I tried to follow the pattern of:
TCEFORM.[TABLE].[COLUMN].config.appearance.fileUploadAllowed = 0
… but with DCE it’s not as straight forward, it seems to be more “nested”.

I’ve tried different combinations but without success.
Maybe there’s another way? Directly within DCE or perhaps completely elsewhere?
I looked all over, but cannot find any answers. I only found a way to disable the “Select & Upload Files” button for each Backend-User, but I would prefer to remove it globally and not have to think about it each time for each (new) user (group).

DCE is using Flexforms to create the fields in your Content Element. I think you need to take a look at your created DCE. And add an appearance entry to the flexform config of the field. But not sure.

To remove the "Select & Upload Files" button in TYPO3, TSConfig doesn't allow direct customization of configuration arrays.
Instead, you can listen to the AfterFlexFormDataStructureParsedEvent event.
Create a FlexFormParsingModifyEventListener Class :
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyVendor\MySitepackage\EventListener;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\Event\AfterFlexFormDataStructureParsedEvent;

final class FlexFormParsingModifyEventListener
{
    public function __invoke(AfterFlexFormDataStructureParsedEvent $event): void
    {
        $identifier = $event->getIdentifier();

        if (
            (($identifier['fieldName'] ?? '') === 'pi_flexform') &&
            (($identifier['tableName'] ?? '') === 'tt_content') &&
            (($identifier['dataStructureKey'] ?? '') === '*,dce_gallery')
        ) {
            $parsedDataStructure = $event->getDataStructure();
            if (isset($parsedDataStructure['sheets']['sheet.tabGeneral']['ROOT']['el']['settings.image']['config'])) {
                $parsedDataStructure['sheets']['sheet.tabGeneral']['ROOT']['el']['settings.image']['config']['appearance']['fileUploadAllowed'] = 0;
            }
            $event->setDataStructure($parsedDataStructure);
        }
    }
}

Register Event Listener in Services.yaml
MyVendor\MySitepackage\EventListener\FlexFormParsingModifyEventListener:
    tags:
        -   name: event.listener
            identifier: 'my_sitepackage/modify-data-structure'
            event: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Configuration\Event\AfterFlexFormDataStructureParsedEvent

Clear BO caches.

Thank you for your reply. The TSConfig code you suggested deleted both buttons, unfortunately. It actually removed the whole section [settings.image]. I would like to only remove the second upload button.

As I mentioned, you can't use TSconfig like this [ config.appearance.fileUploadAllowed = 0 ] there's already an open issue for that. In your case, you should use AfterFlexFormDataStructureParsedEvent to meet your need.

Thank you for your reply. I was hoping there is a way within TSConfig or within DCE itself. I have very little knowledge/experience regarding TYPO3 and TypoScript. Unfortunately I have no clue where and what AfterFlexFormDataStructureParsedEvent is.

I updated my message above to include an example demonstrating how you can achieve this result using events.
